# ValueError In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data Frame with 15 columns suppose out of which i want only 6.
I am performing aggregate and then group by but it is throwing error.

```
def my_compute_function(my_input):

    df = pd.DataFrame(my_input)
    df2 = df[(df['D'] == "Validated")]
    df2[['A','E','F']] = df2[['A','E','F']].apply(pd.to_numeric) 
    df3=df2[['A','B','C','D','E','F']].groupby(['B','C','D']).agg({'A': 
    'max','E': 'max','F': 'max'}).reset_index()

    return df3
```

So i want only 6 columns A,B,C,D,E,F.
When i am adding this line

```
df2[['A','E','F']]=df2[['A','E','F']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

it is throwing error that `ValueError: can not infer schema from empty dataset`.

Comment: Why is your return outside your function? How do you call your function and what does `my_input` look like?

Comment: no sorry its a typing mistake and my_input is a table with 15 columns. as i am using Palantir.

Comment: Please show your input and your desired output. What you are doing can probably done simpler.

Comment: Is possible your `df2` is empty after filtering? What is your pandas version?

Comment: input is 15 columns table lets say A to P. i want 6 columns A to F. Out of which A,E and F are string in original table but i am converting it to numeric as i want max and it should be group by B,C,D.

Comment: And what is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: no but columsn A,E,F has numeric values in original table but the data type is nvarchar so i am only converting the data type @jezrael

Comment: OK, what is pandas version?

Comment: Because if not the last `0.20.3` maybe buggy

Comment: the version is 0.20.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it working perfectly, only `.copy` is necessary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'D':['Validated','Validated','a'], 
'E':['4','8','8'], 
'A':['4','5','8'],
'F':['4','9','8'],
'B':['a','a','r'],
'C':['b','b','b']})

df2=df[(df['D'] == "Validated")].copy()
print (df2)
   A  B  C          D  E  F
0  4  a  b  Validated  4  4
1  5  a  b  Validated  8  9

#for replace ',' to '.' 
df2[['A','E','F']]=df2[['A','E','F']].replace(',','.', regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric)
df3=df2.groupby(['B','C','D']).agg({'A':'max','E': 'max','F': 'max'}).reset_index()
print (df3)
   B  C          D  A  F  E
0  a  b  Validated  5  9  8
```

Comment: okay and one more thing in columns A,E and F i have values with , example 13,444 will it affect the conversion.

Comment: Yes, it will effect. You need `df2[['A','E','F']]=df2[['A','E','F']].replace(',','.', regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric) `

Comment: if i have to add one more conversion statement. df2[['G','H','I']]=df2[['G','H','I']].apply(pd.to_datetime) just below the to_numeric conversion then how will i add because it throws error when i add it like this.

Comment: Whaty kind of error? If some data are custom datetime, need format for specify it. But if some not datetime in column use `df2[['G','H','I']]=df2[['G','H','I']].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')`. Mainly it depends of your format of datetimes